# Dynamically update stored chrome extension config/global data, not in prefs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like my extension to have stored "config" or "meta/global" Constant data, and have the extension update this config data daily from my web server. Things like class names, patterns to match, identifiers, etc.

I can store this data in prefs, but they are async and won't be available when the extension starts up. I need them to be available immediately so the extension can act on them.

Right now I store this data in my extension source itself, so it cannot be updated. But it is available immediately, not async.

Is there a better fix that would allow my extension to update its internal data?

Answer (score 0):

In extensions, you can still have `localStorage` access in non-content scripts, which is synchonous.

However, what's wrong with async `chrome.storage`? It's not going to take a long time to read, you just need to restructure your program to wait for this quite fast initialization.

If you do not want massive restructuring, you could make a synchronous "cache" for it in the script.

```js
// Old:
var settings = { /* hard-coded values*/ }
doSomething(settings[key]);
settings[key] = value;

// New:
function updateCache(changes, area){
  if(area != "local") return;
  for(key in changes){
    settings[key] = changes[key].newValue;
  }
}

function setOption(key, value){
  settings[key] = value; // Synchronous cache update
  var update = {};
  update[key] = value;
  chrome.storage.local.set(update);
}

var settings = { /* set defaults here */ };
chrome.storage.local.get(settings, function(data){
  for(key in data) settings[key] = data[key];
  chrome.storage.onChanged(updateCache);
  /* Old top level code here */
});

doSomething(settings[key]); // Still synchronous
setOption(key, value);
```